# Can you use a middleware on a POST or any other request?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I can't really see anywhere using middlewares on any other request than a GET request, is it normal to use a middleware on a POST or PUT for example?

Comment: From the documentation it is possible to use middleware in PUT (see example in https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-parameters). If this is not the intended response, please edit you question to make you intended answer clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly valid to attach a middleware layer to any kind of requests. Middlewares are a way to add a layer of filtering to check whether the current request fulfills the requirements. It is completely unrelated to the type of HTTP verb of the request and is highly dependent on the purpose the request.

Comment: But if I attach a middleware to a get route but not the post route, it will only run on the get request?

Comment: @Erdss4 No, if you attach a middlware to a route, it runs on that route, not because it was a GET request. You can attach multiple routes of different types to a middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use middleware for post request. Laravel's default authentication is an example of using middleware for post request